# Fabric SDK Go - Peer being excluded by filter when attempting to make a query

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-go

I am attemping the to execute the following statement after instantiation of my chaincode:

```
response, err := client.Query(channel.Request{
    ChaincodeID: heligo.fsConfig.ChainCodeID,
    Fcn: "invoke",
    Args: defaultQueryArgs},
    channel.WithRetry(retry.DefaultChannelOpts),
)
```

But I am getting the following debug log errors:

```
 [fabsdk/fab] 2019/03/06 13:09:55 UTC - fab.(*EndpointConfig).PeerConfig -> DEBU Found MatchingPeerConfig for name/url [peer1.org1.example.com:7051]
 [fabsdk/client] 2019/03/06 13:09:55 UTC - options.(*Params).SetPeerFilter -> DEBU PeerFilter: (options.PeerFilter)(0x8ffd50)
 [fabsdk/util] 2019/03/06 13:09:55 UTC - lazyref.(*Reference).setTimerRunning -> DEBU Timer started
 [fabsdk/util] 2019/03/06 13:09:55 UTC - lazyref.checkTimeStarted -> DEBU Starting timer
 [fabsdk/client] 2019/03/06 13:09:55 UTC - fabricselection.(*selectionFilter).Exclude -> DEBU Calling peer filter on endpoint [peer0.org2.example.com:7051]
 [fabsdk/client] 2019/03/06 13:09:55 UTC - fabricselection.(*selectionFilter).Exclude -> DEBU Excluding peer [peer0.org2.example.com:7051] since it isn't in the set of peers returned by the discovery service
 [fabsdk/common] 2019/03/06 13:09:55 UTC - retry.(*RetryableInvoker).Invoke -> DEBU Failed with err [Failed to get endorsing peers: error getting endorsers from channel response: no endorsement combination can be satisfied] on attempt #1. Checking if retry is warranted...
 [fabsdk/common] 2019/03/06 13:09:55 UTC - retry.(*RetryableInvoker).Invoke -> DEBU ... retry for err [Failed to get endorsing peers: error getting endorsers from channel response: no endorsement combination can be satisfied] is NOT warranted after %!d(MISSING) attempt(s).
Failed to make client query: Failed to get endorsing peers: error getting endorsers from channel response: no endorsement combination can be satisfied
```

I cannot figure out why my peer is being excluded, I am modifying the BYFN sample project and adding my own chaincode.

My endorsement policy is:

```
-P "AND ('Org1MSP.peer','Org2MSP.peer')"
```

And my configuration file is:

```
name: "byfn"
version: 1.0.0
client:
  organization: org1
  logging:
    level: debug
  cryptoconfig:
    path: ../../crypto-config/
  credentialStore:
    path: "/tmp/state-store"
  cryptoStore:
    path: "/tmp/crypto-store"
  BCCSP:
    security:
      enabled: true
      default:
        provider: "SW"
      hashAlgorithm: "SHA2"
      softVerify: true
      level: 256
  tlsCerts:
    client:
      keyfile:
      certfile:

channels:
  heligo-channel:
    peers:
      peer0.org1.example.com:
        endorsingPeer: true
        chaincodeQuery: true
        ledgerQuery: true
        eventSource: true

      peer1.org1.example.com:
        endorsingPeer: true
        chaincodeQuery: true
        ledgerQuery: true
        eventSource: true

      peer0.org2.example.com:
        endorsingPeer: true
        chaincodeQuery: true
        ledgerQuery: true
        eventSource: true

      peer1.org2.example.com:
        endorsingPeer: true
        chaincodeQuery: true
        ledgerQuery: true
        eventSource: true

    policies:
      queryChannelConfig:
        minResponses: 1
        maxTargets: 1
        retryOpts:
          attempts: 5
          initialBackoff: 500ms
          maxBackoff: 5s
          backoffFactor: 2.0

organizations:
  org1:
    mspid: Org1MSP
    cryptoPath: ../../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/{username}@org1.example.com/msp
    users:
      Admin:
        cert:
          path: ../../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem
      User1:
        cert:
          path: ../../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/User1@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts/User1@org1.example.com-cert.pem
    peers:
      - peer0.org1.example.com
      - peer1.org1.example.com
    certificateAuthorities:
      - ca_peerOrg1

  org2:
    mspid: Org2MSP
    cryptoPath: ../../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/{username}@org2.example.com/msp
    users:
      Admin:
        cert:
          path: ../../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@org2.example.com-cert.pem
      User1:
        cert:
          path: ../../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/User1@org2.example.com/msp/signcerts/User1@org2.example.com-cert.pem
    peers:
      - peer0.org2.example.com
      - peer1.org2.example.com
    certificateAuthorities:
      - ca_peerOrg2

orderers:
  orderer.example.com:
    url: localhost:7050
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: orderer.example.com
      keep-alive-time: 0s
      keep-alive-timeout: 20s
      keep-alive-permit: false
      fail-fast: false
      allow-insecure: false
    tlsCACerts:
      path: ../../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/tlsca/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem

peers:
  peer0.org1.example.com:
    url: localhost:7051
    eventUrl: localhost:7053
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer0.org1.example.com
      keep-alive-time: 0s
      keep-alive-timeout: 20s
      keep-alive-permit: false
      fail-fast: false
      allow-insecure: false
    tlsCACerts:
      path: ../../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/tlsca/tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem

  peer1.org1.example.com:
    url: localhost:8051
    eventUrl: localhost:8053
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer1.org1.example.com
      keep-alive-time: 0s
      keep-alive-timeout: 20s
      keep-alive-permit: false
      fail-fast: false
      allow-insecure: false
    tlsCACerts:
      path: ../../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/tlsca/tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem

  peer0.org2.example.com:
    url: localhost:9051
    eventUrl: localhost:9053
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer0.org2.example.com
      keep-alive-time: 0s
      keep-alive-timeout: 20s
      keep-alive-permit: false
      fail-fast: false
      allow-insecure: false
    tlsCACerts:
      path: ../../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/tlsca/tlsca.org2.example.com-cert.pem

  peer1.org2.example.com:
    url: localhost:10051
    eventUrl: localhost:10053
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer1.org2.example.com
      keep-alive-time: 0s
      keep-alive-timeout: 20s
      keep-alive-permit: false
      fail-fast: false
      allow-insecure: false
    tlsCACerts:
      path: ../../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/tlsca/tlsca.org2.example.com-cert.pem

certificateAuthorities:
  ca_peerOrg1:
    url: http://localhost:7054
    httpOptions:
      verify: false
    registrar:
      enrollId: admin
      enrollSecret: adminpw
    caName: ca_peerOrg1
    tlsCACerts:
      path: ../../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem

  ca_peerOrg2:
    url: http://localhost:7064
    httpOptions:
      verify: false
    registrar:
      enrollId: admin
      enrollSecret: adminpw
    caName: ca_peerOrg2
    tlsCACerts:
      path: ../../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/ca/ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem

entityMatchers:
  peer:
    - pattern: (\w*)peer0.org1.example.com(\w*)
      urlSubstitutionExp: localhost:7051
      eventUrlSubstitutionExp: localhost:7053
      sslTargetOverrideUrlSubstitutionExp: peer0.org1.example.com
      mappedHost: peer0.org1.example.com

    - pattern: (\w*)peer1.org1.example.com(\w*)
      urlSubstitutionExp: localhost:8051
      eventUrlSubstitutionExp: localhost:8053
      sslTargetOverrideUrlSubstitutionExp: peer1.org1.example.com
      mappedHost: peer1.org1.example.com

    - pattern: (\w*)peer0.org2.example.com(\w*)
      urlSubstitutionExp: localhost:9051
      eventUrlSubstitutionExp: localhost:9053
      sslTargetOverrideUrlSubstitutionExp: peer0.org2.example.com
      mappedHost: peer0.org2.example.com

    - pattern: (\w*)peer1.org2.example.com(\w*)
      urlSubstitutionExp: localhost:10051
      eventUrlSubstitutionExp: localhost:10053
      sslTargetOverrideUrlSubstitutionExp: peer1.org2.example.com
      mappedHost: peer1.org2.example.com

  orderer:
    - pattern: (\w*)orderer.example.com(\w*)
      urlSubstitutionExp: localhost:7050
      sslTargetOverrideUrlSubstitutionExp: orderer.example.com
      mappedHost: orderer.example.com

  certificateAuthorities:
    - pattern: (\w*)ca_peerOrg1(\w*)
      urlSubstitutionExp: localhost:7054
      mappedHost: ca_peerOrg1

    - pattern: (\w*)ca_peerOrg2(\w*)
      urlSubstitutionExp: localhost:7064
      mappedHost: ca_peerOrg2
```

I have really tried to get to grasp with the issue but am not5 getting anywhere due to the lack of depth in the documentation. Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I had the wrong values for urlSubstitutionExp and eventUrlSubstitutionExp in the entity matcher section. Instead of localhost the values should have been the peer name.